# What's the difference beetwen django database engines?

Tags: django, database

In setting.py file I can that sqlite3 is set by default as db engine. In the docs i read that I can change it to other engines like PostgreSQL MariaDB or MySQL. But here is my question. What for ? Are these engines better/faster than default sqlite3 ? Is there any point of learning how to change database for other than default ?

Comment: YES!  If you want to actually put your app in production, for example in [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/what), you will probably use postgres.  Django gives you a single file, sqlite3 database for testing and developing your code, but no real world app would use it in production.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is very limited database engine. It has limited functionality and only 5 basic types of datatypes. Other engines like PostgreSQL have much more advanced features/fields/datatypes like for example ArrayFields, Full text search etc

You can read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/databases/